# libgdx desktop logging to file

Tags: java, libgdx

I'd like to log exceptions to a file in the desktop version of my program. For this I registered an uncaughtExceptionHandler in my main-Method. But now the exception should be logged to a file - is this possible or do I have to change the System.out? Is this efficient?

Comment: Is change the System.out means u have used    System.setOut(new PrintStream(fileName));
??

If not try this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simple logging, you can use the built-in [feature](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationLogging) of libGDX library.

```
Gdx.app.log("MyTag", "my informative message");
Gdx.app.error("MyTag", "my error message", exception);
Gdx.app.debug("MyTag", "my error message");
```

If you really need to create a file, use [file handling](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling#Desktop_%28Windows,_Linux,_Mac_OS_X%29) of libGDX which is really simple and good for different platforms.

A simple example-

```
FileHandle logFile = Gdx.files.local("log.txt");
```

Then you can have a write method that writes a given log to the file-

```
private void writeLogs(String log){

    logFile.writeString(log, true);
    logFile.writeString("\n", true);

}
```

Comment: I allready did that, the question is, how I can redirect the log output to a file instead of the System.out.

Comment: @morpheus05 I updated the answer with a simple example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where does log.txt end up? what is the path to log.txt on android?